# Не получается открывать другие .html страницы (Flask)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, localhost

Использую Flask. Он не даёт переходить на другие страницы (blog & about). Самостоятельно проблему выявить не смог. Выводит ошибку 404:

> Not Found.
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Вот код, может кто найдёт ошибку:

```python
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/blog')
def blog():
    return render_template('blog.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080, use_reloader=False)
```

Код навигационной ссылки:

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-4"></div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Главная</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="/templates/blog.html">Блог</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="/templates/about.html">Контакты</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `URL` других страниц вводите самостоятельно и после этого ошибка или они прописаны в страницах, например `index.html` и после нажатия на ссылку такое? Если второе, то покажите `index.html` хотя бы. Надеюсь, там ссылки без указания сайта внутри, просто от корня.

Comment: Во всех html файлах находится навигационное меню. Я там ссылки на другие файлы тоже менял, но это ничего не дало, код добавил

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, `/templates/blog.html` - это физическое расположение файла (хотя это тоже неправильно, оно относительное, а не от корня). Но вы то через `@app.route('/blog')` добавляете обработку ссылки `/blog`. Вы определитесь какая должна быть ссылка - в соответствии с физическим расположением `html` файла или нет. Сейчас этим кодом правильно должна обрабатываться ссылка `href="/blog"`, а не то, что у вас в `html` файле написано.

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы я нажимал в меню на блог и попадал на эту страницу. Но фреймворк мне не даёт это сделать. А как ссылка будет выглядеть не важно

Comment: Ещё раз. Попробуйте в `html` файле поменять ссылку на `<a class="nav-link" href="/blog">Блог</a>`

Comment: *А как ссылка будет выглядеть не важно* отличная фраза. Идите читайте документацию про фреймворк

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Ага. Не хочу думать, как должна работать навигация на сайте, главное чтоб работала! ))

Comment: Всё равно не работает. Ещё раз: Есть папка с сайтом, в которой находится файл app.py, и папка templates. В папке templates находятся html файлы. В app у меня получилось прописать ссылку на index, но если я хочу перейти на другие страницы то они не открываются

Comment: Ошибка та же самая? Основное, что вам нужно понять - разницу между физическим расположением файлов и тем, как файлы расположены в виртуальной системе, когда браузер запрашивает их по `URL`. Можно настроить это разными способами, но в общем случае это две разные вещи, а вы этого, похоже, не хотите понимать.

Comment: Да, ошибка осталась

Comment: А если просто через браузер зайти на страницу `/blog` на вашем сервере - та же ошибка? Возможно, сервис нужно перезапускать при изменениях, я не помню. Проверить то легко кэшированная у вас копия страницы или нет, но это ж нужно уметь.

Comment: Если через браузер захожу на страницу то ошибки нет

Comment: Значит или ссылку не так написали в навигации или не перезапустили `flask`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, что уделили время

Comment: Вы начните "от печки" - с простейших примеров на `Flask`, без шаблонов. Добейтесь, чтобы они у вас работали. Потом уже переходите на шаблоны и навигацию. По шагам идите, если вам сложно так сразу осознать разрыв между физическими файлами и тем, как их сервер выдаёт по запросу.